# Сортировать записи из таблицы mysql в определённом порядке

Tags: mysql, база-данных, алгоритм, сортировка

Имеется таблица mysql с записями, которые через php выводятся на страницу в определённом порядке, например: 128, 59, 70, 293, 19 и т.д. Каждая новая запись должна занимать определённое место в данном порядке (порядок записей определяю сам в зависимости от контента). Например, новая запись 476 должна быть вставлена между 59 и 70, т.е. образуется такой массив.

Сейчас я делаю это так: каждой записи даю некоторое число и в запросе указываю сортировку по этим числам. Но я думаю такой алгоритм не очень эффективен, тем более, что данные числа я прописываю вручную.

Есть идеи как можно сделать это по нормальному, не нагружая сильно сервер?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле отдельное поле с идентификаторами задающими порядок - не такая плохая идея. Поле числовое, поэтому сортировка по нему осуществляется очень быстро, оно может быть проиндексировано, поэтому запрос может быть еще более ускорен и практически не зависеть по скорости от объема таблицы.

Заполнять это поле не обязательно вручную, можно прикрутить интерфейс, позволяющий перетаскивать позиции пользователю и пересчитывать это поле автоматически.

Альтернатив не так много и они уже не так эффективны. Например, MySQL-функция `FIELD()`, которая возвращает позицию вхождения первого аргумента в список, который задается оставшимися аргументами.

В качестве первого параметра передается поле `id`, а в качестве остальных аргументов используется список 128, 59, 70, 293, 19. Так как все не входящие в список значения будут получать значение 0, его лучше заменить на 65536

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  IF(FIELD(id, 128, 59, 70, 293, 19) = 0, 65536, FIELD(id, 128, 59, 70, 293, 19))
```

или в качестве альтернативы можно обратить список и использовать ключевое слово `DESC`, тогда значения 0, возвращаемые функций `FIELD()` выстроятся в конец и их можно будет отсортировать по какому-то другому полю

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  FIELD(id, 19, 293, 70, 59, 128) DESC, name;
```

Однако этот подход хуже, чем дополнительное поле, так как вычисления позиции осуществляются при выборки каждой строки, такое динамическое поле невозможно проиндексировать (по крайней мере в MySQL).

Лучше оставить отдельное поле для сортировки, однако рассмотреть возможность его автоматического заполнения. Например, по умолчанию присваивать ему максимальное значение + 1, т.е. размещать в конце, а при перетаскивании элемента, вычислять смещение и изменять (`UPDATE`) это поле у всех строк в интервале смещения.