# Выборка из базы в нужном порядке

Tags: mysql, сортировка

В таблице присутствуют `cat_id` от `116` до `5000`. Запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(cat_id,'155,156,157')
```

Мне выводит все равно `116`, `117`, но никак не `155`, `156`, `157`, `116`, `117`

Тоже не работает:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog` ORDER BY  FIELD(cat_id,'155,156,157')
```

Как сделать правильно? Нужно выводить из базы только по заданному порядку.

Comment: вы что хотите сделать то? чтобы сначала указанные 3 значения были, а потом все остальные в каком то порядке? или что?

Comment: Да! Именно так. А остальные уже шли в другом порядке, который я задам через запятую после order by

Comment: так вы хотите выводить в конце именно те записи которые не встретились в списке, а которые встретились - в начале и в том порядке как в списке ? И могут ли быть отрицательные величины ?

Comment: Нет, отрицательных не будет, это инкремент. 
Мне нужна возможность задавать ЧЕТКИЙ порядок вперед идущих ID, а после уже другая сортировка будет.  Т.е цифры разные, может быть 200,1500,156 и нужен именно такой порядок вывода из БД.

Comment: @php-mvc Так воспользуйтесь ответом Egor Trutnev (который я случайно продублировал, так как он очевиден) только разверните свой конкретный список задом наперед 156,1500,200 (это проще сделать на языке из которого вы запрос формируете, потому что там наверняка есть всякие reverse)

Comment: Вам принципиально это делать именно в SQL? Я бы менял порядок уже в коде php или что там у вас

Comment: ну или пишите явный if (case) прямо в order by который нули (отсутствие в списке) сделает в конце, после чего уже сортируйте по find_in_set

Comment: Да, в SQL, т.к. код огромен там еще после этого 3 сортировки.

Comment: @php-mvc откуда приходит этот список и как он становится именно текстом через запятую ?

Comment: id товаров из поисковой строки приходят в уже готовую модель формы подбора товаров. 

Нужно показать первые найденные из поиска, а далее мы уже показываем то, что форма подбора нашла исходя из condition (цвет - белый и т.п.). Т.е мне нужно показать первые n моделей в самом верху.

Comment: из поисковой строки напрямую в MySQL ничего придти не может, у вас же там есть какой то язык-прослойка, который собственно берет значение поисковой строки и передает его дальше в запрос в MySQL ?

Comment: Мне нужно сделать сортировку средствами MySQL. Я не хочу ковырять модель. Там огромный SQL запрос - и в нем есть заданные id. Мне нужно вывести вначале n-ное количество записей, которые я хочу четко задать в запросе.

Comment: @php-mvc А никто не просит вас делать сортировку другими средствами. Вы можете в коде php перед выполнением запроса сделать единственную правку - сделать array_reverse этого списка перед тем как передать его в запрос. он же у вас там наверняка в массиве изначально ...

Comment: Хм, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Сортировать записи из таблицы mysql в определённом порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539196/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-mysql-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(cat_id,'155,156,157')
```

Приведённый вами код работает, но не совсем так, как вам нужно. Элементы с выбранными id опускаются вниз получаемого списка. Попробуйте поместить id элементов в зеркальном порядке и указать явную сортировку с помощью DESC:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(cat_id,'157,156,155') DESC
```

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM `catalog` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(cat_id,'155,157,156') DESC```   - так уже не работает.  - порядок не тот

Comment: @php-mvc странно. Проверил у себя - всё нормально. Вы уверены, что правильно поняли мои слова. Порядок идёт справа-налево. Т.е., если использовать ваш запрос из комментария, то первым должна быть строка с id 156, потом 157 и 155 в конце.

Comment: Нужен строгий порядок: 
'155,156,157'

Comment: Я уже голову сломал (((

Comment: Порядок может быть любой. 157,155,156 и т.п.

Comment: @php-mvc это нормальный вариант. Всё что вам нужно, просто отразить числа в обратном (зеркальном) порядке. Сделать это без особых проблем можно в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE cat_id IN (1,2,3)
UNION (
    SELECT * FROM `catalog` 
    WHERE cat_id NOT IN (1,2,3) 
    ORDER BY cat_id DESC
)
```

Comment: Неа. Нужен именно порядок. Первые 3 идут вначале, а остальные будут сортироваться далее.