# очерёдность результатов выборки при SELECT ... IN

Tags: sql

есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` IN ('442', '432', '1909', '1809', '466', '449') LIMIT 4
```

Как вывести результаты в том порядке, в котором они указаны?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Выборка из базы в нужном порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712505/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```sql
WITH "order" ("id", "n") AS (
  VALUES
    (1, 1)
  , (3, 2)
  , (2, 3)
  , (4, 4)
)
SELECT "id"
     , "name"
  FROM "users"
  JOIN "order"
       USING ("id")
 ORDER BY "n"
;
```

Частично взято
[оттуда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867578/1892060).
Работает с
[SQLite](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3DnPY2uaAxhndZ5B82ecsa/0),
[PostgreSQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Z1HskDz2MQXojnxcJ9wfe/0),
и, с частичной модификацией, в
[MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jPmNVAxJcKm9aScR7BJjU/1).

Answer (score 0):

вероятно у этих значений есть базой где-то определённый порядок? 
например таблица, в которой значения '442', '432', '1909', '1809', '466', '449' пронумерованы автоинкрементным индексом? тогда надо по left join подсоединять такую таблицу и по её определяющему полю сортировать вывод.

а если это чисто подхалимский приоритет типа иван иваныч должен идти в отчёте после сечина  - вводите в таблицу user колонку приоритета вывода .. и по ней сортируйте вывод.

Answer (score -1):

Порядок перечисления в `IN` не влияет на порядок выборки.

Если приложение динамически генерирует SQL то стандартными средствами сохранение порядка можно добиться так:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '442'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '432'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '1909'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '1809'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '466'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '449'
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: *порядка можно добиться так* Нет.

Comment: @Akina, вроде можно, хотя и медленно может получиться?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если какой-то порядок наблюдается - это случайность.

Comment: @Akina, а есть подтверждающая ссылка? А то ни подтверждение, ни опровержение не гуглится.

Comment: @Qwertiy А что собсно гуглить? По-моему, для любой СУБД аксиоматично, что 1) либо ORDER BY, либо порядок не определён ака несортированная куча; 2) Сортировка в подзапросе в запрос не передаётся. А в данном случае мы имеем запрос из 6 подзапросов с LIMIT, но без ORDER BY - т.е. куча и бардак. То, что этот запрос вернёт первые 4 записи в порядке "получения по тексту" - как раз случайность. Достаточно использовать его как подзапрос-источник данных - и этому порядку карачун.

Comment: @Akina, для запроса - да, а вот про `union all` я ожидал, что он выполняет первый select, потом добавляет результаты следующего и т. д. Подзапроса или сортировки тут нет, так что перемешиваться им вроде бы не с чего. Я пытался гуглить именно описание `union all`, но все останавливаются на том, что он не исключает дубликаты, а про порядок - ни слова. Я всегда считал, что блоки идут в том же порядке, что select'ы, но внутри блоков порядок не определён.

Comment: @Qwertiy Формально считается, что да - сервер как хочет, так и выполняет (и соответственно в таком порядке результат и накапливает). Реально - почему-то получается именно в том порядке, в каком оно по тексту. Но это уже тонкости программной реализации, видимо. Если отдельные подзапросы могут выполняться в отдельных потоках, и начальные подзапросы будут "медленными", возможно, что и получится перемешивание (а, может, и нет) - с другой стороны, а какая разница? Просто считаем, что порядка нет - так спокойнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy *Реально - почему-то получается именно в том порядке, в каком оно по тексту.* Вот пример: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ea546976bd11c2cc6e3120eab380c05 - однако я не уверен, что тенденция сохранится, если результат не влезет в память и будет кэшиться на диск.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107771/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-akina).